# What's wrong with this code from APUE?

Tags: c, linux

Please help me figure out what's wrong with the following code snippet, which comes from APUE section 8.6 (W Richard Stevens, Stephen A Rago
[Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 3rd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637739)):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if ( pid == 0) {
        if ((pid == fork()) < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid > 0)
            exit(0);

        sleep(2);
        printf("second child, parent pid = %ld \n", (long)getppid());
        fflush(stdout);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) != pid) {
        perror("waitpid");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The result from APUE book is:

```
$ ./a.out
$ second child, parent pid = 1
```

The parent `fork` the first child, the first child `fork` the second child, and the first child exit. so the second child's parent will be `init`.However, on my Ubuntu 16.04, the result is:

```
second child, parent pid = 8078
second child, parent pid = 8077
```

The parent `fork` the first child, the first child `fork` the second child, and the first child exit. so the second child's parent will be `init`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, the parent pid must be 1 from the code logic.

Comment: Too many `=` signs in `if ((pid == fork()) < 0) {`.  My compiler told me: `error: comparison of constant ‘0’ with boolean expression is always false [-Werror=bool-compare]`.  If you aren't getting that warning, you're not using enough warning options, or you're using too ancient a version of GCC (mine's 7.1.0 on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 — compiling options `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes fk47.c -o fk47` for source file `fk47.c` containing your code).  I also got a complaint about your main not being `int main(void)`.

Comment: why not just use `return 0` `1` for exiting the main function?

Comment: @mikebayko: That would be better, but the book it is copied from doesn't do that, that's all.

Comment: @zhuo.quan why are you assigning inside of an if statement? If you want to see if `pid < 0` then you should assign `pid = fork();` outside of the if statement's condition.

Comment: @mikebayko, Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Relasted, see [An attempt to backdoor the kernel](https://lwn.net/Articles/57135/) on LWN. Its a very easy mistake to make, and its very easy to overlook during audit. Like @Jonathan said, crank up warnings. `-Wall` at minimum, `-Wall -Wextra` if possible. Overlook the downvotes. Stack Overflow has a problem helping folks new to programming and development. Its a known problem here; see [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)

Comment: each level of sub process, when acting as a parent of a sub sub process should call `wait()` or `waitpid()` before exiting.  As it is (after the correction of '==' changed to '=')  the child/child is still running and its' output will (usually) be displayed after the parent and child have already exited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments to an answer.*</sup>

The problem is too many `=` signs in:

```
 if ((pid == fork()) < 0) {
```

You need:

```
 if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
```

My compiler told me:

```
error: comparison of constant ‘0’ with boolean expression is always false [-Werror=bool-compare]
```

If you aren't getting that warning, you're not using enough warning options, or you're using too ancient a version of GCC.  Mine's GCC 7.1.0 on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 — compiling options:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
    -Wstrict-prototypes fk47.c -o fk47
```

for source file `fk47.c` containing your code. I also got a complaint about your `main` not being `int main(void)`.

In my opinion, you can't afford to compile without using options close to what I use; you'll miss too many simple bugs.  Remember, the C compiler knows more about C than you do, and it will tell you when you're doing it wrong if you ask it to do so.

---

Separately, [mike bayko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6684651/mike-bayko) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395371/whats-wrong-with-this-code-from-apue#comment77751648_45395371):

> Why not just use `return 0` (or `1`) for exiting the `main` function?

The basic answer is "because that isn't what the book does".  I prefer `return` from `main` when the code is in `main()`, but code usually migrates into a function other than `main()`, and then `exit()` — or one of its quick variants — becomes relevant.

And [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395371/whats-wrong-with-this-code-from-apue#comment77751687_45395371):

> Why are you assigning inside of an `if` statement? If you want to see if `pid < 0` then you should assign `pid = fork();` outside of the if statement's condition.

There's no problem with doing the assignment in the `if` statement if it is coded accurately, and using the assignment can prevent code from marching off the RHS of the page in a long chain of `if (…) … else if (…) … else if (…) …` operations.  Here, it wouldn't make much difference, but in other contexts it is fine and not something to complain about.